# onClickOut (click after leaving the element)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem was that I need a **"onClickOut"-Event**.

For example:
You have a DIV viewing on hovering (onMouseOver) some Button or what ever.

If you click outside the element it needs to hide, but if you say *$("body").click* it also will be hidden when you click into the element itself. :/

Now I listen the mouseposition and when *mouseleave()* I set a var on clicking into my element. In the next step I listen a generelly click-event (body) but I ask if the var was set. If not it has to be a click outside my element, so I can hide my element.

I hope you can use it:

```
$("#schnellsuche_box").mouseleave(function() {
    var inside;
    $("#schnellsuche_box").click(function() {
        inside = true;
    });
    $("body").click(function() {
        if(!inside) {
            $("#schnellsuche_box").hide();
        }
    });
    delete inside;
});
```

Comment: Note: you can't `delete` a local variable. (But even if you could, it wouldn't make sense here because your click handlers try to use that variable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do that by listening to a click on the document level, and inside the event handler you check if the clicked element was `#schnellsuche_box` or any element inside `#schnellsuche_box` by using `closest()`, like so :

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#schnellsuche_box').length ) 
         $('#schnellsuche_box').hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CsMPn/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the `#schnellsuche_box` click event from bubbling up to the `body` click event (that's default event propagation) by doing `return false`:

```
$("#schnellsuche_box").click(function() {
    inside = true;

    return false;
});
```

Comment: `event.stopPropogation();` will work too, I have been told that `return false` stops bubbling only when used in jquery callbacks

Comment: @rps Yeah that will work, but that's not exclusive to jQuery, it works in just JavaScript too.

Comment: I'm not sure what "it" is referring to in your comment *" it works in just JavaScript too"*, but if it is `return false;`, then it will only prevent the default event in "non-jQuery" event handlers, not event propagation.

Comment: Think he means native-JS (non-jQuery) //event.stopPropogation()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
   var $target = $(e.target);
   if (!$target.is('#schnellsuche_box') &&
       !$target.parents('#schnellsuche_box').length) {
       alert('outside');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#schnellsuche_box").on("click",function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @F4r-20 You don't have to, `event` refers to the current JavaScript event.

Comment: I didn't know, thanks.

Comment: @mattytommo -  at least it does if you're using IE and some versions of Chrome. It should be defined as a parameter.

Comment: This will fail in older IE versions (which don't support `stopPropogation`) and in Firefox (which doesn't provide a global `event` object). Define the event handler so that it accepts `event as first argument and it will work fine. jQuery passes an augmented event object to event handlers, which solves these browser differences.

Comment: @FelixKling now okay?